# rules of using javascript GOTO , LABEL etc

Tags: javascript, label, goto

Can anybody help me in understanding the use of goto , label etc in javascript, I have a program where I need to jump directly to a particular block of code...I am trying to use "break labelName" , but its showing an error that "labelName not found". Is there any rule to use label with break or continue
Thanks in advance .

Answer (score 0):

You must be new to javaScript ;)

Anyhow: defining a function is defining your named excess point:

```
function doSomething(someVariable){
    alert(someVariable);
}
```

So, somewhere else in your code you can now call `doSomething('Hello world!');`

Calling the function as above is the `GOTO` part and `doSomething` correlates to `LABEL`. As you see you can also pass some parameters (here it's `someVariable`) to the function (the executing code block) and work with it (like here the `alert` that causes an alert box showing in your browser showing the assigned value 'Hello world!'.

Maybe this also helps you: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function or  http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_functions.asp

Comment: Yes, I am new to js :)....I know about functions but I just want to know how to use label with break or continue etc...